Unreliable bind-mounts
On a RHEL8-based virtual machine running systemd 239, I have the following bind-mount setup:

a filesystem (identified via UUID) mounted to a "source" mount-point (/path/to/sourcemnt)
multiple sub-directories on that "source" mount-point:
/path/to/sourcemnt/dirA
/path/to/sourcemnt/dirB
/path/to/sourcemnt/dirC


bind-mounts for each sub-directory to "target" mount-points

The fstab looks like this:
# auto-generated entries for 'sourcemnt'
UUID=<...>               /path/to/sourcemnt       ext4  defaults                                   1 2

# manually added entries for bind mounts
/path/to/sourcemnt/dirA  /path/to/targetmnt/dirA  none  bind,x-systemd.requires=/path/to/sourcemnt 0 0
/path/to/sourcemnt/dirB  /path/to/targetmnt/dirB  none  bind,x-systemd.requires=/path/to/sourcemnt 0 0
/path/to/sourcemnt/dirC  /path/to/targetmnt/dirC  none  bind,x-systemd.requires=/path/to/sourcemnt 0 0

The Problem
Not all of the bind-mounts are automatically mounted during boot. This can be seen from the ownership/permissions of the mount-points as well as output of findmnt and mountpoint commands.

The journalctl output doesn't contain error messages trying to mount the "failed" bind-mounts, they are simply never mentioned. Only the successfully mounted bind-mounts are mentioned in the usual way:
<Date> <Hostname> systemd[1]: Mounting /path/to/sourcemnt...
...
<Date> <Hostname> systemd[1]: Mounted /path/to/sourcemnt.
<Date> <Hostname> systemd[1]: Mounting /path/to/targetmnt/dirB...
...
<Date> <Hostname> systemd[1]: Mounted /path/to/targetmnt/dirB.


Manually mounting them (as root) works.
The number of "failing" bind-mounts is not consistent on re-boot. Sometimes only one is missing, sometimes two, but at least one is always successfully mounted.
Changing the order in which the bind-mounts are specified in the fstab doesn't change which of them are mounted and which are not.
It seems that the one lexicographically in the middle of the sort-order (dirB) is always there, dirA sometimes and dirC only after a hard restart (if at all) - but I didn't try often enough to say for sure.
The same setup still worked as of RHEL7

This looks like a timing problem/race condition, but how can I ensure that all bind-mounts are present? I even tried to "cascade" the mount-requirements as in
/path/to/sourcemnt/dirA  /path/to/targetmnt/dirA  none  bind,x-systemd.requires=/path/to/sourcemnt 0 0
/path/to/sourcemnt/dirB  /path/to/targetmnt/dirB  none  bind,x-systemd.requires=/path/to/targetmnt/dirA 0 0
/path/to/sourcemnt/dirC  /path/to/targetmnt/dirC  none  bind,x-systemd.requires=/path/to/targetmnt/dirB 0 0

but that also didn't help (that said, why should it in the first place?).

I was seeing a similar problem, but in my case the source disk was mounted via NFS.
I was sometimes seeing dependency loops at bootup which would cause other services to fail (eg named-chroot).
In the end I was unable to fix it so I cheated.  I created an rc.local script that waited until the source was available and then did the bind mounts there.
m()
{
  cnt=0
  while [ ! -e $1 -a $cnt -lt 10 ]
  do
    sleep 1
    cnt=$((cnt+1))
  done
  
  mount -o bind -r $1 $2
}

m /datadisk/netboot/kvm/boot /var/lib/tftpboot/9cdc29af
m /datadisk/netboot/econet-bridge/boot /var/lib/tftpboot/661b168a

Messy, but it works!

In the end, I did the same ;) It would still have been nice to figure out what caused the problem, though ...
